# How to express the tasks in a list and the order is related to priority?

Tags: sentence-construction

How to express the tasks in a list and the order is related to priority?

I thought it could be

**Today's tasks with priority are**

Task1: AA

Task2: BB

Task3: CC

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *"Today's tasks in order of priority."*

Or

> *"Today's tasks in order of importance."*

You can plug in whatever word you want:

> Today's tasks in order of...